# Add button value to data on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a set of buttons with different amounts.

```
 <div v-for="banknote in banknotes" :key="banknote.id">
  <q-btn @click="addCashAmount(banknote)">{{banknote.amount}}</q-btn>
 </div>
```

Each click I want to add the amount of the button clicked. banknote.amount is a decimal

Having set `cash_amount: ''` in data, how do I get `cash_amount` to update each time I click a button? I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
addCashAmount(banknote) {
   this.cash_amount += banknote.amount
},
```

Comment: What does happen? Are there any console errors? Is `cash_amount` not changing at all or is it changing incorrectly? If you add console logging to `addCashAmount` are the values of `banknote.amount` and `this.cash_amount` as expected?

Comment: this.cash_amount returns list of amounts instead of sum. For instance if banknote.amount are 10000 and 5000 it returns 100005000 instead of 15000

Comment: Probably you initialize this.cash_amount with [] instead of 0.

Comment: You are right I initialized it as '' instead of 0. It works now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is that `banknote.amount` is a string rather than a number.

If possible you should fix the values in `banknotes` so that the `amount` values are all numbers.

If not, you could coerce to a number when performing the addition:

```js
addCashAmount(banknote) {
   this.cash_amount += +banknote.amount
},
```

Here I've used a unary `+` to perform the coercion. If you prefer a different method, such as calling `Number`, that should work too:

```js
addCashAmount(banknote) {
   this.cash_amount += Number(banknote.amount)
},
```

You should also check that the initial value of `cash_amount` is the number `0` and not the string `'0'` or the empty string `''` as that would cause a similar problem.

Comment: Yes I initialized it as '' and I was looking in the wrong place. Thanks a lot